# Android - API visible using charls proxy in release app - How to secure api details in release app?

Tags: android, charles-proxy

In my release app I am able to get the api details using charls. However in other apps charls shows unknown in case of api details.

How can I achieve the same? I need to secure the api.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use https instead of http in the base url